# handling printer from php application

Tags: lamp, printers

My server based application need to directly handle printer. the problem is that i am using php as my web application language. My applcation runs on LAMP platform.

i have tried couple of methods. but ididn't find any useful. please advise me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate a bit?

Is it local printer? Network printer? Is priniter connected to server or client? Have you tried [this](http://my.php.net/manual/en/ref.printer.php)?

Comment: its network printer. the link that u gave me is for windows server.. it wont work in linux server

Comment: then use shell_exec() and printing command in your OS. for linux it should be something like "lp: or "lpr" command. see http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Printing-HOWTO.html for details.